# Proof of (MV Calculus) Chain Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Ok, so I'm trying to understand the proof of the Chain Rule from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, so I (hopefully correctly) opened up the entire proof to try to understand all the algebra and the roles of the epsilons and deltas in the proof. I'd like to get feedback on if what I did looks fine (even though it looks horrible):

Theorem (Chain Rule): If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $a$, and $g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable at $f(a)$, then the 
composition $g \circ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable at $a$, and $$D(g \circ f)(a)=Dg(f(a)) \circ Df(a).$$

Proof: Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $a$, and $g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable at $f(a)$.

This means that $$(1) \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=0,$$ and that $$(2) \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert g(f(a)+h)-g(f(a))-[Dg(f(a))](h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=0.$$

Note then that 
$$\frac{\lvert (g \circ f)(a+h)-(g \circ f)(a)-[Dg(f(a)) \circ Df(a)](h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=$$ $$\frac{\lvert g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))-Dg(f(a))[Df(a)(h)] \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=$$
$$\frac{\lvert g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))-Dg(f(a))[f(a+h)-f(a)-f(a+h)+f(a)+Df(a)(h)] \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} \leq$$
$$\frac{\lvert g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))-Dg(f(a))[f(a+h)-f(a)] \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}+\frac{\lvert Dg(f(a))[f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)] \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}.$$

But by (2), for every $\epsilon >0$, we can find $\delta >0$ such that $0<\lvert k \rvert<\delta$ implies that $\lvert g(f(a)+k)-g(f(a))-[Dg(f(a))](k) \rvert<\epsilon \lvert k \rvert$; in particular, if $0<\lvert f(a+h)-f(a) \rvert<\delta$ for any $h$ satisfying $0<\lvert h \rvert<\rho$ for a suitable $\rho>0$, then 
$$\frac{\lvert g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))-Dg(f(a))[f(a+h)-f(a)] \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}<$$
$$\frac{\epsilon \lvert f(a+h)-f(a) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=$$
$$\frac{\epsilon \lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)+Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} \leq$$
$$\frac{\epsilon \lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} + \frac{\epsilon \lvert Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}.$$

Now, since $Df(a)$ and $Dg(f(a))$ are linear transformations, we also have that for certain $M,N \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\lvert Df(a)(h) \rvert<M\lvert h \rvert$$ and 
$$\lvert Dg(f(a))[f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)] \rvert<N\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) \rvert.$$

This in turn gives first that
$$\frac{\epsilon \lvert Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}<M \epsilon,$$
and also, by using (1), that for every $\epsilon >0$ we can find $\delta >0$ such that $\lvert h \rvert<\delta$ implies that $\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) \rvert<\epsilon \lvert h \rvert$, from which we also obtain 
$$\frac{\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}<\epsilon$$ and
$$\frac{\lvert Dg(f(a))[f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)] \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}<$$
$$\frac{N\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}<$$
$$\frac{N \epsilon \lvert h \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=N \epsilon.$$

Finally, piecing all of the above together (from the last three inequalities we can conclude that both terms on the right hand side of the original inequality are arbitrarily small) gives the conclusion: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert (g \circ f)(a+h)-(g \circ f)(a)-[Dg(f(a)) \circ Df(a)](h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}=0.$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine to me!

The big insight needed for the proof really is that finite dimensional linear maps must have finite operator norms, which follows from the fact that the unit ball is compact in finite dimensions.  This is the step where you say there is an $N$ with $|A(x)| \leq N|x|$ for each total derivative.

Best luck reading Spivak!  It is a great book.

Comment: Yeah, I skipped saying anything about this part on the proof because in the book it's part of an earlier problem (you probably know that already but anyway...).

Anyway, thank you very much Steven. Hope to see you guys again on next run of M2O2C2 or something.

Comment: Hey!  Great to see an M2O2C2 student still putting in the hard work learning multi V!